# Invariant Violation: Objects are not valid as a React child (using react-native object inside json)

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, react-native

Using React-Native:

I'll start off with what I have..

Example Code of json file:

And any "..." used is just for my string values that don't really pertain to the question, it would be just distracting to look at

```
[
{
"id": "question1"
"label": "..."
"option": [ { "order": 1, "name": "..."},
            { "order": 2, "name": "..."},
            { "order": 3, "name": "..."}
          ]
},
{
"id": "question2"
"label": "..."
"option": [ { "order": 1, "name": "..."},
            { "order": 2, "name": "..."},
            { "order": 3, "name": "..."}
          ]
},
{
"id": "question3"
"label": "..."
"option": [ { "order": 1, "name": "..."},
            { "order": 2, "name": "..."},
            { "order": 3, "name": "..."}
          ]
},

and so on....
```

Render code under class

"data1" is just what i called the json file when I imported, ex: import data1 from "../../...."

```
render(){
   return(
      <View
         <FlatList
         data={data1}
         showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
         renderItem={this.renderItem}
         keyExtractor={(item,index) => index.toString()}
         />
      </View>
   );
}
```

renderItem code

```
renderItem = ({item}) => {
   return(
      <View
         <TouchableOpacity>
          <Text {item.id} </Text>
         </TouchableOpacity>
         <TouchableOpacity>
          <Text {item.label} </Text>
         </TouchableOpacity>
         <TouchableOpacity>
          <Text {item.option} </Text>  /* here is where I get the error because option is an object! */
         </TouchableOpacity>
          <Text {item.name} </Text>    /* this doesn't work either obviously */
         </TouchableOpacity>
```

I know I cant access option because it is an object but I want to be able to access the keys within it (order and name)

item.id and item.label work because they are not in the object "option". I just can't seem to figure out how to access the keys to use in the app.

For reference, it is a survey app (hence the TouchableOpacity) the "label" is a question for user and the object "option" and its "name" are the various answers the user can click.

I think I might have to map it but I'm not quite sure how to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`item.option` is an array of objects, but not an array of JSX. You can either stringify it (probably not what you want), or you, as you suspect, can map the array to renderable JSX.

```
<Text>
  {item.option.map(({ order, name }) => (
    <div>
      order: {order}, name: {name}
    </div>
  ))}
</Text>
```

This is the idiomatic way to render lists, or arrays, of data objects in react. React-native takes it a step further and provides a built-in component to handle rendering lists. [`Flatlist`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist) to the rescue.

```
<FlatList
  data={item.option} // <-- pass the array object
  renderItem={({ item: { order, name } }) => ( // <-- your render item function
    <div>
      order: {order}, name: {name}
    </div>
  )}
/>
```

Putting it all together it'll look something like this:

```
renderOption = ({ item: { order, name } }) => (
  <div>
    order: {order}, name: {name}
  </div>
);

renderItem = ({item}) => {
   return(
      <View
         <TouchableOpacity>
          <Text {item.id} </Text>
         </TouchableOpacity>
         <TouchableOpacity>
          <Text {item.label} </Text>
         </TouchableOpacity>
         <TouchableOpacity>
         <FlatList
           data={item.option}
           renderItem={this.renderOption}
/>
         </TouchableOpacity>
          <Text {item.name} </Text>    /* this doesn't work either obviously */
         </TouchableOpacity>
       </View>
    );
}

render(){
   return(
      <View
         <FlatList
         data={data1}
         showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
         renderItem={this.renderItem}
         keyExtractor={(item,index) => index.toString()}
         />
      </View>
   );
}
```

Comment: This makes sense. I won't have access to the code until tomorrow to test it. Would I be implementing and adding the {({ item: {order,name}}) into my original renderItem code and then adding order: {order}, name: {name} into the View?

Comment: Yes, a flatlist within a flatlist. You could do it within your original renderItem, but now it "nested" and starts to lead to less readable code. Whatever you render in the nested flatlist will be in the outer flatlist, not the view. I'll update my answer with an enbiggened context.